# Partial View and Model not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I"m working in MVC 3 with Razor views.  I've created a page that calls a partial view

```
@Html.Partial("_FeaturedRatesBox")
```

which looks like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<AppleWeb.Models.RateViewer>

<div class="col">
<h3>Today's Featured Rates</h3>
<form method="post" action="">
  <div class="tabber">
    <ul class="tabs unstyled">
      <li class="selected"><a href="#tab1">Loans</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab2">Deposits</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab" id="tab1">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="rate"> <span class="left">@item.AccountName <br />
        </span> <span class="right"> As low as <span class="percent">@item.Rate</span></span></div>
        <!-- end of rate -->
    }
    </div>
    <!-- end of tab -->
    <div class="tab" id="tab2"> Loremipsum
    </div>
    <!-- end of tab -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn alignright">Apply Now</button>
  </div>
  <!-- end of tabber -->
</form>
</div>
```

and the `rateviewer.cs` model looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.EntityModel;
using AppleWeb.Models;

namespace AppleWeb.Models
{
    public class RateViewer
    {
        private PublicWebEntities pubDB = new PublicWebEntities();
        public virtual IEnumerable<DepositRate> FeaturedRatesDeposit()
        {
            var data = from item in pubDB.DepositRates
                       where item.Featured.Equals(true)
                       select item;
            return data.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

It errors out on the line calling the partial view and says

> CS1061: 'AppleWeb.Models.RateViewer' does not contain a definition for 'AccountName' and no extension method 'AccountName' accepting a first argument of type 'AppleWeb.Models.RateViewer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly

Well AccountName and Rate are both entity names for the DepositRates Entity Object.  From the DataModel.Designer file:

```
public static DepositRate CreateDepositRate(global::System.Int32 rateID, global::System.String accountName, global::System.Double rate, global::System.Double aPY, global::System.Int16 sortingOrder)
{
    DepositRate depositRate = new DepositRate();
    depositRate.RateID = rateID;
    depositRate.AccountName = accountName;
    depositRate.Rate = rate;
    depositRate.APY = aPY;
    depositRate.SortingOrder = sortingOrder;
    return depositRate;
}
```

I'd hope to make this work as such, because then I can use this model elsewhere on the site.

Comment: What are you trying to show in you `foreach` loop? Your model is a collection of `RateViewer` objects, and the `RateViewer` does not have an `AccountName` property. If it is indeed intended to have a *collection* of `RateViewer` objects as the model for the partial view, you need a nested `foreach` loop (looping through `item.FeaturedRatesDeposit`). Otherwise, change the model to `RateViewer` and go with what @Andreas recommends in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate the IEnumerable property on your Model ie. `@foreach (var item in Model.FeaturedRatesDeposit)`

Comment: You're probably on the right track, but looks like the model for the partial view should be of type `RateViewer`, rather than `IEnumerable<RateViewer>`.

Comment: Yakimych is ofcourse right. The view needs to use either a single rateViewer as the model or do a nested `@foreach (var rateDeposit in item.FeaturedRatesDeposit())` iteration

Comment: change the foreach over to FeaturedRatesDeposit gives me

Foreach cannot operate on a 'method group'. Did you intend to invoke the 'method group'?

Comment: @techmaniac - you should add `()` after `FeaturedRatesDeposit`, since you're invoking the method.

Comment: So it it was a combination of the changed listed above (call FeaturedDeposits(), remove IEnumerable from using statement on partial)  ANNNNNNNND changing the RateViewer code to 

var data = pubDB.DepositRates.Where(i=>i.Featured==true);

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an object which is an IEnumerable of type AppleWeb.Models.RateViewer to the view,

so the code should look like:

```
@Html.Partial("_FeaturedRatesBox", new List<AppleWeb.Models.RateViewer>())

"new List<AppleWeb.Models.RateViewer>()" can be replaced with the actual instance of the collection you want to pass to the view.
```

Also, the type "RateViewer" does not contain any field called "AccountName".

Comment: That is true in order to actually pass a model to the view but the compiler error that is mentioned in the question comes from the fact that the type RateViewer does not have an AccountName property. Therefore actually passing the view a RateViewer or IEnumerable<RateViewer> (which is the expected model type) will not fix the compiler error.

Comment: @AndreasSabroeJydebjerg : You are right. I have edited the answer to reflect that.